# Saving promises from fetch call in java script

Tags: javascript, fetch

Whenever I try making fetch get api calls I am not able to save the result of it in my other JavaScript variables. either nothing happens or I get something like '[object Promise]'.
What exactly am I doing wrong in this specific call and/or code?

users.js:

```
async function githubUsers() {
  let response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  let users = await response.json()
  console.log(users)
  return users
}

githubUsers()
let allUsers= githubUsers()
let UsersWidget = `
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Current Online users: ${allUsers}</p>
  </div>
</div>`
```

I have a main.js file where I call upon it:

main.js

```
document.writeln(UsersWidget);
```

and here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Github users</title>
    <link href="css/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/users.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-blue-500">
test
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `await` the result of that `Promise`. Even if you dont explicitly return a `Promise` from `githubUsers` the return value is a `Promise` because it's an `async` function:

```
let allUsers = await githubUsers()
```

If you can't use `await` because not in the context of an `async` function, write this:

```
const allUsers = githubUsers().then(users => {
  return `
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>Current Online users: ${users}</p>
    </div>
  </div>`
});
```

In main.js:

```
allUsers.then(x => document.writeln(x));
```

Comment: when doing that i get the following error:
await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: it probably works but I believe the problem is somewhere else since I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man you have to put all of the code that uses `UsersWidget` in place of the comment

Comment: that is all the code. i just want to show the list of gihub users

Comment: Then you probably have something like `element.innerHTML = UsersWidget`

Comment: i do render them on a main.js file using document.writeln(WeatherWidget);

Comment: That code should also be adapted to handle `Promises`. I'd have to see the full code to help you more.

Comment: Ill update the op

Comment: op updated with a little more info. that's is basically all the code so far.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man please take a look at my edit

Comment: i am getting the error: "TypeError: Illegal invocation" now

Comment: OK that was a last detail missing, please check my last edit

Answer (score 1):

You need an await enclosed in an IIFE as

```
(async () => {
    let allUsers = await githubUsers()
    let UsersWidget = `
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Current Online users: ${allUsers}</p>
      </div>
    </div>`
})();
```

We want to wait for `githubUsers` before we can populate `UsersWidget` and as this invocation is not enclosed inside a context function, you need a surrounding IIFE

Comment: when doing that i get the following error: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules